# React router history.push is not adding path from root?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a autocomplete input field in my react app, base on the user selection react-router will redirect to the product detail page.

My product detail page path is structured as below:

```js
<Route extact path={'/:category/:id'} component={ProductDetailContainer}/>
```

In my autocomplete, I have an `onChange` function that will trigger the redirect.

```js
const handleChange(event, value) => {
   history.push(`${value.category}/${value.id}`) 
}
```

While this works when the user is in base URL path `'/'`, it will fail if the user attempt to use the autocomplete field in `ProductDetailContainer` due to the path has been added on top of the current path again, it will then become a path like this `'/:PrevCategory/:NewCategory/:id'`

I tried to use  `replace` but it seems to do the same thing. So is there a way to reset history to base url before push()?

#Edit 1
This is where the to autocomplete field and history are a push.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress'
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
....
}));

const TitleBar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const loading = open && options.length === 0;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    if (!loading) {
      return undefined
    }

    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(site)

      const products = await response.json();
      
      if (active){
        setOptions(products)
      }

    })();

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };

  }, [loading])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      setOptions([]);
    }
  }, [open])

  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    if (value !== null) {
      // redirect to product detail page if user selected an item
      history.replace(`${value.category}/${value.id}`)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <div className={classes.search}>

            <Autocomplete
              id='aysncSearchBar'
              style={{ width : 300}}
              open={open}
              onOpen={()=>{setOpen(true)}}
              onClose={()=>{setOpen(false)}}
              getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id = value.id}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
              options={options.sort((a,b) => -b.category.localeCompare(a.category))}
              groupBy={(option) => option.category}
              loading={loading}
              onChange={handleChange}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField 
                  {...params}
                  label="Search"  
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: (
                      <React.Fragment>
                        {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                      </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              )}

            />
          </div>

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TitleBar;
```

Comment: How do you get your history object?

Comment: const history = useHistory(); if that is what you are asking. I followed the instruction from react router site https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Would like to see your Component with JSX too,. Edit question to include both :)

Comment: hmm, Great. Let me see what is going on. Hope for best my friend :)

Comment: Sure, added component.

Comment: You should define the base app path in env file and use that in history's push method if you want the behaviour you need @user2232355

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the base `/` while pushing.. if you do not have base `/`, il will keep appending.

```
history.push(`/${value.category}/${value.id}`)
```

Comment: oh wow, I can't believe I missed this part. Appreciate your help !

Comment: Glad i could help you :) Please do not forget the vote :)